# What does this symbol on a contactor represent?

Tags: power-electronics

What does this symbol represent?  It is connected to a contactor.

[image]

Comment: I'd guess a bicolor LED (ignoring the 'contactor' reference) with 2 leads. Such as [this](http://betlux.com/product/LED_lamp/Dual%20Color%20LED(2Pins)/BL-L517.PDF).

Comment: It may be (an equivalent circuit of) triac as well. Can you please show the surrounding electronics/schematics?

Comment: This symbol isn't standard and makes little sense with the "diode + line" symbols. Someone made it up and it is that person's task to explain what it is.

Comment: I got it, Its a Soft starter, And THIS IS A STANDARD SYMBOL FOR A SOFT STARTER

Comment: Soft starters are made with triac(s)...

Comment: @krishnalalkl  Why are you shouting?  If you want to let everyone know what it is, then write an answer.

Comment: @HandyHowie: Who Said anything about Shouting, And as u can see i already wrote down the answer, Please see the above comment

Comment: OK, using Google to search for "soft starter symbol" and looking at images tab: Hmm, in these symbols the diodes do look like **Thyristors** instead of diodes with a weird line. So again: this is **not** a standard symbol. The thyristors are drawn in the wrong way. It was drawn by someone who didn't stick to the general consensus regarding thyristor symbols. Yes it's a detail but getting your details right defines the difference between pro and amateur (at least in my opinion).

Comment: @krishnalalkl Your "THIS IS A STANDARD SYMBOL FOR A SOFT STARTER" is all capitals and therfore shouting. You're using a **comment** now, to write an answer (in the proper way) use the textbox below and press the "Post Your Answer"  button.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie: ohh T hers is an Option for that i didn't see that, Thanks for that.

Comment: @HandyHowie : first of all let me apologize for the mistake i have made in typing thats caps lock, which i didnt know it meant shouting. anyway i just wanted to draw attention to the answer only. Since Mr.  Bimpelrekki Showed me That there is an option to write your answer here,I am Not much of Internet guy, only uses the web if i have any queries.

Answer (score 3):

It represents a softstarter (the components shown inside are SCR - Silicon Controlled Rectifiers).
Obs: This is not a standard IEC symbol.

Answer (score 1):

The symbol represents a **triac**, of which the gates of the thyristors are drawn weird. (see other remarks).
It is **part** of a softstarter, a the softstarter also contains electronics for controlling the gate(s) of the triac(s).

Answer (score 0):

The symbol represents a **soft starter**, which is used for smooth starting and stopping of the motor.

Here it shows 2 SCR devices connected in inverse parallel connection.

Comment: Maybe. Those are not standard thyristor symbols. Proper symbols have the gate connection entering at the cathode. It might be a lazy draftsman's symbol.